# Is there any way to use EF Core Power Tools from command line, or package manager window?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-power-tools

**Context**

I am using EF Core Power Tools in my ASP.NET 7 WebAPI project.
I can use it via the GUI, set the options then generate the classes.

**Question**

Is there any way to use EF Core Power Tools from command line, or package manager window?

Comment: Yes  it is possible https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#requirements

Comment: many thx, I meant EF Core Power Tools CLI, or just a launcher with not command line options, which reads the json then emits the output.

Comment: Did you read the link??

Comment: Yes, my bad, still can not find... Btw I read the EF  Core docs even before  posting the question, again it is probably my bad not finding any answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CLI for EF Core Power Tools from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools.Cli